# NextAuth.js Facebook provider

Tags: facebook, next.js, facebook-login, next-auth

How did you deal with "the email address cannot be returned for accounts created on mobile devices" using NextAuth.js Facebook provider

I need to store user email in DB

Comment: When the user signed up for Facebook using their mobile, then Facebook might not have an email address for them. If you want to store it only as an identifier, then make something up - userid@fakehost. If you want it to be able to contact the user - then you'll have to implement a step for them to enter (and confirm) it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If user have not set an email address, email field value will be **null** in the response. I check the email this way:

```
  if (user.email === null) {
    throw new Error("Email address is required");
  }
```

Comment: Where do you add this code?